# UIStackView & Gestures

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uistackview

I'm trying to get/keep a handle on elements in my UIStackView after I have moved it with a pan gesture.

For example, the elements I am trying to grab a handle on are things like the button tag or the text label text.

The code explained…

I am creating a UIStackView, via the function `func createButtonStack(label: String, btnTag: Int) -> UIStackView`

It contains a button and a text label.

When the button stack is created, I attach a pan gesture to it so I can move the button around the screen.  The following 3 points work.

1. I get the button stack created
2. I can press the button and call the fun to print my message.
3. I can move the button stack.

The issue I have is…

Once I move the button stack the first time and the if statement `gesture.type == .ended` line is triggered, I lose control of the button stack.

That is, the button presses no longer work nor can I move it around any longer.

Can anyone please help?  Thanks

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        let ButtonStack = createButtonStack(label: “Button One”, btnTag: 1)

        view.addSubview(ButtonStack)

        ButtonStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        ButtonStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        let panGuesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pan(guesture:)))

        ButtonStack.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        ButtonStack.addGestureRecognizer(panGuesture)
    }

    func createButtonStack(label: String, btnTag: Int) -> UIStackView {

        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage( imageLiteral(resourceName: "star-in-circle"), for: .normal)
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
        button.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        button.tag = btnTag

        switch btnTag {
        case 1:
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(printMessage), for: .touchUpInside)
        case 2:
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        //Text Label
        let textLabel = UILabel()
        textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        textLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
        textLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25.0).isActive = true
        textLabel.font = textLabel.font.withSize(15)
        textLabel.text = label
        textLabel.textAlignment = .center

        //Stack View
        let buttonStack = UIStackView()
        buttonStack.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
        buttonStack.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.equalSpacing
        buttonStack.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
        buttonStack.spacing   = 1.0

        buttonStack.addArrangedSubview(button)
        buttonStack.addArrangedSubview(textLabel)
        buttonStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return buttonStack
    }

   @objc  func printMessage() {
        print(“Button One was pressed”)
    }

    @objc func pan(guesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = guesture.translation(in: self.view)

        if let guestureView = guesture.view {
            guestureView.center = CGPoint(x: guestureView.center.x + translation.x, y: guestureView.center.y + translation.y)

            if guesture.state == .ended {                
                print("Guesture Center - Ended = \(guestureView.center)")
            }
        }
        guesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
    }
```

Comment: I have executed the same code posted by you. And it is working perfectly fine. Even after moving the stack view to a different position, I am able to tap the button without any issue.

Comment: @PGDev .  Thank you for your insight.  It has given me something to think about in the fact that my one button is behaving as it should.  My real project has multiple buttons that 'should' behave the same way, but don't after they have been moved.  I will look closer into the rest of my code and try to find out why one button works, but not multiple buttons.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using autolayout on the buttonStack you can't manipulate the `guestureView.center` centerX directly. You have to work with the constraints to achieve the drag effect. 
So instead of `ButtonStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true` you should do something along the lines of:

```
let centerXConstraint = ButtonStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor)
centerXConstraint.isActive = true
ButtonStack.centerXConstraint = centerXConstraint
```

To do it like this you should declare a weak property of type `NSLayoutConstraint` on the `ButtonStack` class. You can do the same thing for the centerY constraint.

After that in the `func pan(guesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer)` method you can manipulate the `centerXConstraint` and `centerYConstraint` properties directly on the ButtonStack view.

Also, I see you are not setting the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to false on the ButtonStack. You should do that whenever you are using autolayout programatically.

Comment: Thank you marosoaie, I will look into using the weak NSLayoutConstraint properties.  As for the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on the buttonStack, I set this on the line before I return the buttonStack within the `createButtonStack` function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to PGDev and marosoaie for their input.  Both provided insight for me to figure this one out.

My code worked with just the one button, but my project had three buttons inside a UIStackView.

Once I moved one button, it effectively broke the UIStackView and I lost control over the moved button.

The fix here was to take the three buttons out of the UIStackView and I can now move and control all three buttons without issues.

As for keeping a handle on the button / text field UIStackView, this was achieved by adding a `.tag` to the UIStackView.

Once I moved the element, the `.ended` action of the pan could access the `.tag` and therefore allow me to identify which button stack was moved.

Thanks again for all of the input.